# Format Phone Number in a Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL as well as Oracle. I was playing with Oracle. I tried to have a constraint on phone number so it only allows the phone number to be inserted in a specific way.

**Below is my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE FIRSTTRY(
USERID CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
EMAILADDRESS VARCHAR(40),
PHONENUMBER VARCHAR(12),
PROFILEPICTURE BLOB,
PRIMARY KEY(USERID)
);
```

I put the constraint on phone number like this:

```
ALTER TABLE FIRST_TRY
ADD CONSTRAINT FIRSTTRY_PHONENUMBER CHECK 
(PHONENUMBER LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
OR PHONENUMBER LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
OR PHONENUMBER LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

I am inserting the values to the table like this:

```
INSERT INTO FIRST_TRY VALUES (1,'ABCD','ABCD@YAHOO.COM','0504562893',NULL);
```

But it gives me an error:
**Here is the error:**

```
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check

*Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint.
```

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: It seems to me you are checking for digits but inserting string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE FIRST_TRY
ADD CONSTRAINT FIRST_TRY_PHONENUMBER 
CHECK (regexp_like (PHONENUMBER,'^(\d{3}-\d{3}-?\d{4}|\d{10})$'))
```

---

```
INSERT INTO FIRST_TRY VALUES (1,'ABCD','ABCD@YAHOO.COM','0504562893'  ,NULL);
INSERT INTO FIRST_TRY VALUES (2,'ABCD','ABCD@YAHOO.COM','050-4562893' ,NULL);
INSERT INTO FIRST_TRY VALUES (3,'ABCD','ABCD@YAHOO.COM','050-456-2893',NULL);
```